# is it possible to build an id3 decision tree using scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

So I'm trying to build an ID3 decision tree but in sklearn's documentation, the algo they use is CART. But I also read that ID3 uses Entropy and Information Gain to construct a decision tree.

Tried `dtree=DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy')` but the resulting tree is unreliable.

What parameters should I edit in `DecisionTreeClassifier()` to get an ID3 decision tree?

Comment: you may use python implementation of the ID3 instead. Please refer to this codehttps://github.com/tofti/python-id3-trees/blob/master/id3.py

Comment: What you did was correct but it is not clear what you mean by *unreliable tree*. Can you provide more details, please?

Answer (score 0):

You may use python implementation of ID3 similar to the one [here](https://github.com/tofti/python-id3-trees/blob/master/id3.py)